# Why do you need the "::before" css modifier for the fontawesome chevron to show in the following bootstrap accordion code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm looking at adding arrows to the bootstrap accordion and came across this example on codeplay: https://codepen.io/tmg/pen/PQVBGB
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
           <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[data-toggle="collapse"] .fa::before {  
  content: "\f139";
}

[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .fa::before{
  content: "\f13a";
}
```

If i remove the ::before modifiers in the CSS the chevron disappears entirely. But shouldn't the content change regardless of whether it's positioned before or after? Also as a side question in the above code, ::after doesn't actually insert it after the text "collapsible group item #1" text. Why is that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content` only works with virtual elements such as `::before` and `::after`.

`::after` adds a virtual child element that appears after the parent's other children. The element that you've applied the class `fa` is the `<i>` element. In your situation, `::after` adds a virtual child element that appears after any other children of `<i>` since `fa` is a class on that `<i>`. (So, answering your side question, the virtual element doesn't move because its parent, `<i>`, doesn't move.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Makes complete sense.

Comment: I'm in a good mood today, take this +1 to go to 10K reputation :-)